# How to detect slide event direction in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Im trying to detect the `slide` direction in a Bootstrap 4 carousel when user triggers the `slide` event. Is there a way to do this?

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
      //Detect if the slide direction it was to the left or to the right
});
```

Comment: There's a `direction` property on the event which you may find useful: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for [`direction`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#events) property

```js
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  console.log(e.direction)
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```